# IEEE Latex Listing

Tags: listings, ieeetran

Here is a minimal version of my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsocconf]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=single,language=C}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=matrix multiplication pseudo  
 code,linewidth=8.7cm,label=lst1:mxm]

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("hello! ");
}
\end{lstlisting}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,IEEEexample}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of my pseudo code]

My questions:

- How can i add a space after the caption ?
- How can reduce the size of the police of the pseudo code ?

Thanks a lot.
Best Regards.

Comment: Can you please add the `\documentclass` line?

Comment: ok :) it's done :)

Comment: What do you mean with "size of police"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Class `IEEEtran` only distinguishes between `table` and `figure` captions. When the caption is made (`\@makecaption`), it checks for `table` and sets the space `\abovecaptionskip` below, otherwise `\abovecaptionskip` is set above the caption. `\belowcaptionskip` is not used. Table captions should be set above the table and figure captions below. Since the listings caption is set above, the following redefinition of `\lst@makecaption` tricks `IEEEtran` to think a listings is a table to put the space below the caption.

The empty space above the first source line with contents is removed by removing the empty line.

The font size of the listings can be changed by using option `basicstyle`.

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  frame=single,
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\small,
}

\makeatletter
\def\lst@makecaption{%
  \def\@captype{table}%
  \@makecaption
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
  caption=Matrix multiplication pseudo code,
  label=lst1:mxm,
]
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("hello! ");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]