# Error using caption in listings, IEEE Access template

Tags: listings, captions, templates, ieeetran, lstlisting

I'm am using the [IEEE Access Latex template](https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-article/use-authoring-tools-and-ieee-article-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-ieee-access/) and I'm getting errors when using the `caption` command in a listing environment. This does not happen with the IEEEtran template.

For example, this code works:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{lstlisting}[label=listing1, language=C]
int main(void)
{
        printf("Hello world\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

But the following does not, and the only difference is the `caption` command:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{lstlisting}[label=listing1, language=C, caption=Listing 1]
int main(void)
{
        printf("Hello world\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

In fact, the result is a series of errors like this:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   \@makecaption ...capfont #2\strut }\ifdim \xfigwd 
>   \columnwidth \setbox \@te...
>   l.12 ...el=listing1, language=C, caption=Listing1]
>
> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
>
> l.12 ...el=listing1, language=C, caption=Listing1]
>
> ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
>
> l.12 ...el=listing1, language=C, caption=Listing1]
>
> ! Infinite glue shrinkage found on current page.
>   \@makecaption ...\ }}{\vss \raggedright \noindent 
>                                                     \unhbox \@tempboxa \figcap...
>   l.12 ...el=listing1, language=C, caption=Listing1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ieeeaccess` redefines the caption command and uses a length called `\xfigwd` which is normally set from a figure or table environment. As you listing uses neither of these environments, you'll have to manually do it:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begingroup
\newlength{\xfigwd}
\setlength{\xfigwd}{\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[label=listing1, language=C, caption={hgd}]
int main(void)
{
        printf("Hello world\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\endgroup
\EOD

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still struggling with this problem here is my solution:

Put your listing in `minipage` and remove the indent for new paragraph with `\hspace*{-\parindent}%` (it's a hint from [Why is the minipage indented on the left?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152582/why-is-the-minipage-indented-on-the-left)

```
\hspace*{-\parindent}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[label=listing1, language=C, caption={hgd}]
int main(void)
{
        printf("Hello world\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
```

and add this `\makeatletter` snippet after including `listings` package and before `\begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\lst@makecaption{%
  \def\@captype{table}%
  \@makecaption
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
```

it makes `ieeeaccess` treats listing's caption like a table's caption and adds extra vertical space between caption and listing. This snippet is taken from: [IEEE Latex Listing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248804/ieee-latex-listing)